# Channel Entries - Possible to combine specifying specific ids and excluding other ids?

Tags: channel-entries

Is it possible to do something like the condition below in channel entries?

`Get all ids that are 88,99 and 100 but not 200,300 or 400`

The examples in the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#entry-id-from), only shows to get certain ids

```
entry_id="13|42|147"
```

or exclude certain ids

```
entry_id="not 45|534|807"
```

I want to combine getting certain ids and excluding certain ids.

Is this possible?

Comment: Passing id's you require is the same as excluding all id's you don't want leaving the ones you do... The logic doesnt make sense, can you expand ?

Comment: @stuartmcd69 I think my problem is that the ids are gotten from 2 difference sources and I need to sort of combine them, even if some of the parts doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

As stuart says passing all the id's you would like to include should automatically exclude all those not passed in the entry_id parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, there is no native way to include and exclude in one channel tag.

Whilst I don't appreciate your requirements, I'd look at Stash by Croxton. It will allow you to capture multiple entries from multiple channesl using whatever logic you require.

Comment: here is a question and answer on how to compare two lists with stash, that might help. http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/17501/stash-ee-compare-2-lists